# Changing CSS class based on model if statement RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, helper

I have an app where a product can have a regular price or a discounted price both of which are saved in two seperate columns in my database as: price and offer.

I have a controller called 'generals' which is for all general products.

What I would like to happen is that if 'general.offer' is blank then the div that wraps the price will have a class of 'product-price'. If however there is a value present in general.offer then the div will have a class of 'product-special-price'.

Currently I have the following:

```
#View

<div class="<%= product_price %>">
  <%= general.price %>
</div> 


#Application Helper

def product_price
   if general.offer.blank?
      return "product-price"
   else
      return "product-special-price"
   end
end
```

At the moment I am receiving a wrong number of arguments error. Any advice people have on how to fix this would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Michael, Sorry the error I am receiving is `undefined local variable or method general for #<#<Class:0x61fc908>:0x5dce1d8>`. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should pass `general` to `product_price` but depends on the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks Michael, How would I pass general into product_price. Would it be using @general defined in my generals controller ie. @general.offer.blank? When doing this I am left with error `undefined method offer for nil:NilClass`

Comment: There's no magic in Rails! You need to pass it explicitly `product_price(general)`, both in declaration and when you call it.